# generate a random number with given bit size in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to generate a random number with aribitorary bit size in Rust using Rug. I create a function like this:

```
fn bit_str(bitlen: usize) -> String {
    let vs = vec!['0','1'];
    let mut nums = vec!['0'; bitlen];
    for i in 0..bitlen {
        nums[i] = *vs.choose(&mut rand::thread_rng()).unwrap();
    }
    return nums.into_iter().collect::<String>();
}
let bin = bit_str(1_000_000);
let mut random_number = Integer::new();
random_number.assign(Integer::parse_radix(bin,2).unwrap());
```

But this is slow. In my environment, it took 30 seconds to generate 100 random numbers with 1m bits. Is there any way to generate such random numbers faster?

Comment: When you benchmarked your code, did you compile in release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is akin to apilat's, but uses [`rug`](https://docs.rs/rug/latest/rug/) and generates as big of chunks as possible (at most 32 bits, which is the maximum [`rug::rand::RandState::bits`](https://docs.rs/rug/latest/rug/rand/struct.RandState.html#method.bits) supports):

```
/*
[dependencies]
rug = "*"
*/

fn rand(mut bits: u32) -> rug::Integer {
    let mut rand = rug::rand::RandState::new();

    let mut res = rug::Integer::with_capacity(bits as usize);

    while bits > 0 {
        let generate = bits.min(32);

        res = (res << generate) + rand.bits(generate);
        
        bits -= generate;
    }

    res
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:b}", rand(1_000_000));
}
```

[Rustexplorer.](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Arug%20%3D%20%22*%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Afn%20rand(mut%20bits%3A%20u32)%20-%3E%20rug%3A%3AInteger%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20rand%20%3D%20rug%3A%3Arand%3A%3ARandState%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20res%20%3D%20rug%3A%3AInteger%3A%3Awith_capacity(bits%20as%20usize)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20bits%20%3E%200%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20generate%20%3D%20bits.min(32)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20res%20%3D%20(res%20%3C%3C%20generate)%20%2B%20rand.bits(generate)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bits%20-%3D%20generate%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20res%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3Ab%7D%22%2C%20rand(1_000_000))%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

In general, working with integers directly is much faster than working with strings and then converting.
The operation of appending a bit `b` at the end of an existing number `x`
can be implemented by bit-shifting `x` one to the left and then adding `b`: `(x << 1) + b`.
This is the principle behind the implementation below.

I couldn't figure out where your `Integer` type comes from so the example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a290de5bd642ad5983f38eca5c2ef5b9)) uses `num::BigInt` instead.
You could make this code even faster by generating bits in larger chunks (for example 32 or 64 bits) at the cost of some implementation complexity.

```
use num::BigInt;
use rand::{Rng, thread_rng};

fn randint(bits: usize) -> BigInt {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let mut x = BigInt::default();
    for _ in 0..bits {
        x <<= 1;
        x += rng.gen_range(0..=1);
    }
    x
}

fn main() {
    let x = randint(10);
    let y = randint(1000);
    println!("{x}");
    println!("{y}");
}
```